# After importing firebase in app.js I initialized but in controller firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, webauthn

This is in my app.js where I import firebase and initialized it

```
    const firebase = require('firebase');

    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: ************,
      authDomain: ****************,
      databaseURL: **********",
      projectId: ********,
      storageBucket: ***********,
      messagingSenderId: **********,
      appId: *********,
      measurementId: *********
    });

    app.use( (req, res, next) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {
            req.session.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
      });
      res.locals.isAuthed = req.session.isLoggedIn;
      res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
      next();
    });
```

But in auth.js Controller after importing firebase it wont work

```
    const firebase = require('firebase');

    exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
     const name = req.body.name;
     const email = req.body.email;
     const password = req.body.password;
     const confirmPassword = req.body.password;

     if(password === confirmPassword){
        
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
            const user = new User({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                cart: {items: []}
            });
            return user.save();
        })
        .then(result => {
            res.redirect('/login');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                //'auth/wrong-password'
                req.flash('error', 'Already Registered');
                return res.redirect('/signup');
            }
        });  
    }
```

This error occurs
TypeError: firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function
at exports.postSignup (/media/rishav/Project Space/Projects/Web Development/Node Express/Controllers/auth.js:95:23)

```
    const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

    // Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
    const serviceAccount = require("../Data/firebase-service-account.json");

    // Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
    firebase.initializeApp({
      credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "****",
      databaseAuthVariableOverride: null
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to say:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...)
```

Notice the parenthesis after "auth".

But the bigger issue is that you shouldn't use the Firebase web client library in your nodejs application.  Instead, you should use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which is an entirely different module, and runs with admin privileges initialized by a service account.  You can use that to [create user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) in your backend code.